# mysql query to add entries of multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have a query in mysql which gives me this

```
product    count(*)
-------    ---------
A           5
B           2
C           3
D           4
E           1
```

the query is simple like

```
select product,count(*) from dashboard group by product;
```

Now the problem is I wanted to merge the count of some products into other product so for example the expected output is

```
product    count(*)
-------    ---------
A           7
C           3
D           5
```

so count(A)=count(A) + count(B)

count(c) = count(C)

count(D)= count(D) + count(E)

I was thinking something like this

```
select case
when product = 'A' OR product = 'B' then ----
when product = 'C' then ----
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group your existing results a second time (this has the significant advantage that it will use an index, if possible, to perform the first aggregation and then a much simpler sum over the smaller resultset to perform the second):

```
SELECT   CASE
           WHEN p IN ('A','B') THEN 'A'
           WHEN p IN ('C')     THEN 'C'
           WHEN p IN ('D','E') THEN 'D'
         END AS product, SUM(c)
FROM     (
           SELECT   product AS p, COUNT(*) AS c
           FROM     dashboard
           GROUP BY p
         ) t
GROUP BY product
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57884/1/0).

Comment: so `group by` uses the selected data rather than the table data ? (if that makes sense ?)

Comment: @ManseUK: I take that back; I tested it and it didn't work as expected.  Better to alias the column unambiguously.

Comment: @eggyal : can you suggest me a book or website which could help me to learn these type of advanced queries and also which are better performance wise like you commented on bluefeet's  post

Comment: @BhavikShah: The best thing that you could do is read the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/) - for the most part, it's very accessible and well-written and you can learn pretty much everything there is to know from it.

Comment: @eggyal : also can I set a default value in case. like if the product is not in A,B,C,D,E then OTHER

Comment: @BhavikShah: Yes, just before the `END` keyword insert `ELSE 'OTHER'`.

Comment: I did `WHEN p NOT IN ('') THEN 'Other'` just wanna make sure it is optimal to use it

Comment: @BhavikShah: There is a difference: if `p` is `''` or `NULL` it will be caught by the `ELSE` but not by your version.  I'd not worry about which is "optimal" (the difference will be negligible unless there are a substantial number of `product` values not caught by the earlier clauses), but rather focus on which is *correct* to one's needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the changes to the product in a subquery:

```
select product, count(*) Total
from
(
  select 
    case
        when product in ('A','B') then 'A'
        when product in ('C')     then 'C'
        when product in ('D','E') then 'D'
     end AS product
  from dashboard
) src
group by product;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7af3e/3)

Comment: Not very index-friendly.  Better to do the grouping first (using an index) then aggregate the groups after.